# How to convert String(January 2013) to Date(201301) value in SAS?

Tags: sas, date-format

I want to convert a String to Date in SAS, I tried:

```
data _null_; 
   monyyyy = 'January 2013'; 
   date = input(substr(strip(monyyyy),1,12),YYMMN.);;
   put date=YYMMN.; 
   run;
```

i want output like :- date = 201301

Comment: Do you want date to be numeric? Be aware, that it wil not be a valid SAS date as it will not represent an actual date.

Comment: My first preference is in date format, second in numeric. but YYMMN. is valid date format. if we can convert numeric then its easy to convert to date format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data _null_; 
   dt = 'January 2013'; 
   date = input(cats('01', substr(dt, 1, 3), substr(dt, length(dt)-4)), date9.);
   put date= yymmn.; 
run;
```